# how to use linear-gradient on a background shorthand rule?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, shorthand

Why do I get a different result with this:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black), 
  linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black) 0 0, 30px 30px/60px 60px  #eee;
}
```

while trying to get the result I get with this:

```
body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black), 
  linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-position:0 0, 30px 30px;
}
```

?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/isaacalves/pen/OWoQGP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short hand for this would be:

```css
body {
  background: 
    0 0/60px 60px linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black), 
    30px 30px/60px 60px linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black) #eee;
}
```

You need to set the position and size for each background image

Answer (score 2):

You just got the syntax slightly wrong here:

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%,
              transparent 75%, black 75%, black),
            linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%,
              transparent 75%, black 75%, black) 0 0, 30px 30px/60px 60px  #eee;
                                                   ^^^
```

That comma here is wrong - it needs to end

```
              transparent 75%, black 75%, black) 0 0 30px 30px/60px 60px  #eee;
```